# NOSQL and RDBMS used by same application

Tags: node.js, nosql, rdbms

Can anyone point to me of any examples in which i can use an RDBMS to maintain data but use a NOSQL database to pushout data.  My goal is to add/update/delete to the RDBMS but store entities with all of thier related data in the NOSQL database.  Then, I would like to push the data out from NOSQL.  Does this sound like a bad idea?   My goal is to have nodejs present this data in a hierarchal format of all of its related data.

Comment: Ehh? You want to keep the same data in two different database engines? Sounds like a very bad idea. (or I might have misunderstood you)

Comment: I agree.  The issue is that I have a Rails app that pushes data to a postgres db.  However, I want a way to push the data in its relational form using nodejs without constructing the data on nodejs. Maybe uses rails active record directly from nodejs and return the results?

Comment: Why can't you switch to your nosql database for your rails app?

Comment: I also think it's a bad idea. Decide for one database. If you want subsets of data in NoSQL but all data in an RDBMS you can work with the _changes-Feed in NoSQL and database triggers to synchronize data.

Comment: @jgauffin - I was thinking of using mongo but from what I read about it, i am concerned about atomicity and consistency.

Comment: I don't think you should use two different database engines in an app, unless you are trying to upgrade from one to another.

Comment: Sounds to me that you don't really have to use a NoSQL and are not ready for one.

Comment: I think you are right.  I will have nodje talk to rails to get the data and return it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said it sounds like you want to store all youre data in 2 different engines, and I can not see the big idea in that unless we are migrating to a new system.

If you are afraid of the nosql consistency and your data do fit in youre rdbms I can't see the point in using the nosql when you can have node connect to your rdbms and fetch the data stright from that.

have a look at [driver for postgresql](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) it is a driver for postgresql. I haven't tried it, but it look's like its fairly developed and tested.

Comment: I actually am using that.  However, I want a JSON representation of my entities and their children.  This is easily done in rails but I would like to do the same in node.